# How to escape quotes that passed from a JSON file to Jade template?

Tags: json, pug

I have some variables stored in a JSON file which will be injected into my generated HTML later. Those variables would be put in places like:

```
var str = '#{content.str}';
```

While in the JSON file the content.str might contain `'` in it, and it would cause the JavaScript error after rendering the HTML file.

What should I do to prevent this happening?

Thanks,

Comment: do you need #{content.str} instead of '#{content.str}'?

Comment: @HarpreetSingh the JSON variable is `I've done it`. What I expected is `var str = 'I\'v done it';`

Answer (score 0):

It's simple -

```
"I've done it".replace("'", "\\'")
//output "I\'ve done it"
```

Using RegEx - replace all

```
"I've done it haven't you".replace(/'/g, "\\'")
//output "I\'ve done it haven\'t you"
```

Comment: is your problem resolved? if yes then please accept it, if not then add a comment

Comment: Sorry, I missed the notification for this. Actually the trouble is that the generated HTML should have a `\`` instead of `'`. I guess I should do it in the Template Rendering step, but I don't now how to do that. Currently I'm rendering it like this: `jade.render(template, json_options);`